# Making USB device stable and reliable

Tags: usb

On my iMAC:

```
iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015)
Processor 4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
Memory 16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
Graphics AMD Radeon R9 M395X 4GB
```

I have created a Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine in ORACLE VirtualBox 7.0:

```
VirtualBox Graphic User Interface
Version 7.0.14 r161095 (Qt5.15.2)
```

Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Raspbian version:

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Raspbian is running on a 64GB SD Card on a Raspberry Pi 0 W, I have a CAN Adapter USB module plugged into the Pi 0.

I've set-up the Raspbian OS to share the USB device and from Ubuntu I can see the device as if it were connected to the local system.

The problem I'm having is that the adapter doesn't always come up successfully every time so I need a way to detect this and restart it without rebooting the entire Pi, I need this to be bullet proof and reliable.

How can this be done?

I also have *usbreset* in the command set so I tried:

```
root@RPi0:~# usbreset 1d50:60f6
Resetting candleLight USB to CAN adapter ... ok
```

However, running ip link and still no can0.  Whatever usbreset does it isn't the same as unplugging the USB and reconnecting it.

After much searching around, it turns out that a lot of set-up information is inaccurate or out of date.  The biggest issue which really got me going around in circles is that because I am using Raspberry Pi Imager v1.8.5 which as par of the set-up has dialogs to set-up the WiFi, as a result there is no need to transfer ssh or wpa_supplicant.conf files because this is handled by the imager.

The Raspberry Pi Imager version I am using on my iMAC is v1.8.5

Comment: what does the imac with virtualbox and a ubuntu guest have to do with the problem? Have you investigated any known issues with the *CAN Adapter USB module* - perhaps it's a power issue (I don't know, do these devices need much power?) - when it doesn't come up successfully, anything in the system logs to indicate an error? i.e. output of `dmesg` can usually show problems with peripheral devices

Comment: @JaromandaX, I included it so everyone  has the complete picture, last night I refreshed the SSD card using Ubuntu 22.04 and started over, now its working reliably so all I can think is that the system became unreliable after updating, which I won't do again now its stable.